# Extract a subset of tree from random forest model for prediction

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

From Liaw's classification and regression by RF paper, "The best way to determine how many trees are necessary is to compare predictions made by a forest to predictions made by a subset of forest"

I am wondering if there is a way to extract subtree for prediction with R's randomForest package. getTree seems to print out the structure. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one in **randomForest**, `predict(rf, dat, predict.all=TRUE)`, you can get predictions from all the sub trees.