# Is there a way to get the instances used for classification in random forest tree in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, feature-extraction, feature-selection

The `getTree` function in randomForest package in R displays the structure of the a particular tree used in the random forest.

Here is an example on the iris dataset

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris)
getTree(rf, 1)
```

This shows the output of tree #1 of 500:

```
   left daughter right daughter split var split point status prediction
1              2              3         3        2.50      1          0
2              0              0         0        0.00     -1          1
3              4              5         4        1.65      1          0
4              6              7         4        1.35      1          0
5              8              9         3        4.85      1          0
6              0              0         0        0.00     -1          2
7             10             11         2        3.10      1          0
8             12             13         4        1.55      1          0
9              0              0         0        0.00     -1          3
10             0              0         0        0.00     -1          3
11             0              0         0        0.00     -1          2
12            14             15         2        2.55      1          0
13             0              0         0        0.00     -1          2
14            16             17         2        2.35      1          0
15             0              0         0        0.00     -1          3
16             0              0         0        0.00     -1          3
17             0              0         0        0.00     -1          2
```

The leaves are the nodes with 0 leaf daughter and 0 right daughter.

Is there a way I can get which instances (rows of the iris data set) are in those leaves?
Like   Node 2 which is a leaf has instance 2,3,4 from iris dataset all classified as 1.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Building on this answer:

[Extract a subset of tree from random forest model for prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567893/extract-a-subset-of-tree-from-random-forest-model-for-prediction)

There may be an access function I'm not aware of, but the following manual approach seems to work:

```
rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, keep.forest=TRUE)
pr_nodes <- attr(predict(rf, iris, nodes=TRUE),'nodes')

pr_nodes[,1] # array of 150 node assignments for 1st of 500 trees
```

Comment: thanks but can you explain the second line of your code? what is attr and why you write nodes = TRUE?  It will be really helpful if you can explain your code a little. Thank you

Comment: @rmania you will find the `help` (or `?`) function very help-ful.  For example, try `help(attr)` to find out what `attr()` does, or `?predict` to find out what `nodes=TRUE` does.  I could cut and paste documentation, but if you have an R console it's right there in front of you.

Comment: no i understand what attr and predict does, I just want to understand what is the logic behind using the predict function to get the instances. As far i know predict function is used for predictions from the results of RF but how did it help to get the instances?   Sorry if this is a silly question but I just got a little confused

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I am interested in this as well, what is the logic behind using predict function to get the instances.  Doesnt predict function is used for predictions from the results of RF?  how is it useful in getting back the instances?